# Сортировка элементов в ListView с CursorAdapter

Tags: java, android, listview, adapter

У меня есть свой адаптер для `ListView`, унаследованный от `SimpleCursorAdapter`. В каждом айтеме у меня 2 `TextView` и `CheckBox`. Состояния чекбоксов загружаются из базы данных. Нужно реализовать следующее: сначала в списке отображаются только айтемы с нечекнутыми чекбоксами (в колонке `'complete'` в БД стоит **0**). А после них - айтемы с чекнутыми чекбоксами (в колонке стоит **1**).

**Что я сделал**

1. Сначала я проявил лень и решил сделать два списка. Все отлично, вот только были проблемы с прокруткой. И вообще, это костыльно. Как-то не хорошо получается.
2. Решил отфильтровать `boolean` массив с состояниями чекбоксов (сначала `false`, потом `true`). Получилось. Но между чекбоксами и текстом в айтеме, и вообще по id записи не было соответствия. Так как я изменил порядок чекбоксов, а все остальное не трогал.
3. Решил вообще переписать адаптер, хорошо пошла мысль, но после компиляции и запуска приложение вылетало с миллиардом ошибок, в которых я не смог разобраться. После этих всех грабель, я не выдержал и решил спросить у вас, народ.

**Код адаптера**

Как я все делал, уже не помню, поэтому вернул код в изначальное положение. Где список отображается *как есть*.

```
public class ListCursorAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter
{
    private int layout;
    public ListCursorAdapter(Context _context, int _layout, Cursor _cursor, String[] _from, int[] _to) {
        super(_context, _layout, _cursor, _from, _to);
        layout = _layout;

    }
    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context _context, Cursor _cursor) {

        String list_name = _cursor.getString(_cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.LIST_NAME));
        String list_data = _cursor.getString(_cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.LIST_TIME));
        int chb_list = _cursor.getInt(_cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.LIST_COMPLETE));
        TextView name_list_tv = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.lv_list_name);
        TextView data_list_tv = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.lv_list_data);
        CheckBox chb_lists = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.chb_list_complete);
        chb_lists.setClickable(false);
        chb_lists.setFocusable(false);
        name_list_tv.setText(list_name);
        data_list_tv.setText(list_data);

        chb_lists.setChecked(chb_list==1);
    }




    @Override
    public View newView(Context _context, Cursor _cursor, ViewGroup _parent)
    {

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)_context.getSystemService(_context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View view = inflater.inflate(layout, _parent, false);
        return view;
    }
}
```

Что мне нужно:

В `ListView` сейчас данные из базы отображаются как есть, по порядку. Мне нужно этот порядок **изменить**: сначала идут айтемы с данными из строк базы с нулями в колонке `'complete'`. Затем в списке должны отобрадаться айтемы с данными из строк базы с единицами. Иными словами, сначала мне нужно показать айтемы с чекбоксами состояния `false`, а затем - с `true`. А не как сейчас - данные из БД просто берутся и по очереди помещаются в айтемы. Нужно очередь сбить

Как решить эту проблему?

Comment: Можно или изначально делать запрос в базу с указанием в коаком порядке отсортировать данные (в вашем случае по boolean колонке) или отказаться от курсора вообще, сделать свою модель данных (класс, представляющий запись в БД) помещать инфу из БД в него и уже список этих классов сортировать средствами явы.

Comment: в методе `query`, через который делается запрос к БД, есть параметр orderBy (седьмой параметр), который отсортирует курсор в соотвествии с вашими пожеланиями/ А быть нужно так, как я вам и говорил - читать книжки, а не придумывать нереальные костыли, на которые тратить напрасное время.

Comment: @pavlofff, книжки? Какие? Нет денег чтобы их купить. А в инете - старье дветыщипервогодовые

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, ничего не понял..

Comment: `public class Row{ int id; String someData; String anotherData; boolean someBoolean; //getters and setters}` После получения данных из БД записывайте их в список экземпляров этого класса. Далее сортируйте его компаратором по нужному полю и отображаете в списке. Ну или да - сортируйте как @pavlofff предлагает сразу при наполнении курсора из БД.

Comment: Я вам советовал книги уже. Прочитав их вы станете лучше, чем будете их не читая. По крайней мере дикие костыли должны будут перестать приходить вам в голову. Найти обе эти книги в инете не проблема вовсе.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Адаптер к решению данной проблемы никакого отношения не имеет. Назначение адаптера - отобразить предоставленные данные, а не что то там сортировать, переставлять и подменять в них.

Для того, чтобы получить желаемый вами результат, вы должны оформить соответствующий запрос к БД, чтобы данные (курсор), передаваемые в адаптер, попадали туда уже в нужном виде. Для этого в методе [`query()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#query(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[],%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[],%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)), с помощью которого вы посылаете запрос в БД есть параметр *orderBy* - отсортировать полученный в выборке результат. Поскольку самого вашего запроса к БД в вопросе нет, то приведу абстрактный пример:

```
Cursor cursor = BDHelper.query("mytable", null, null, null, null, null, "complete");
```

где *complete* - имя столбца в БД, по которому необходимо сортировать.

К имени столбца можно добавить служебное слово языка SQL - *DESC* - сортировать в порядке возрастания, но этот порядок используется по умолчанию и его можно опустить:

```
Cursor cursor = BDHelper.query("mytable", null, null, null, null, null, "complete DESC");
```

Для сортировки в порядке убывания следует добавить служебное слово языка SQL - *ASC*

```
Cursor cursor = BDHelper.query("mytable", null, null, null, null, null, "complete ASC");
```

[почитать](http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/76-urok-36-sqlite-podrobnee-pro-metod-query-uslovie-sortirovka-gruppirovka) об этом

PS: метод `query()` имеет несколько перегрузок и в самом простом варианте принимает следующие аргументы:

```
query (String table, String[] columns, String selection, String[] selectionArgs, String groupBy, String having, String orderBy)
```

то есть, по порядку: имя таблицы, имена колонок в результирующей выборке, условие выборки, аргументы для условия выборки, группировка, фильтр для сгруппированных, сортировка

Comment: спасибо!! Не смотрел даже в сторону query()...