# Краш android приложения с savedInstanceState

Tags: java, android, eclipse

Лабораторная работа в универе. Делаю всё по примеру, но при использовании БД для сохранения данных класса SQLiteOpenHelper программа крашится в эмуляторе (на физ. устройстве тоже). Eclipse ошибку не выдает. 
Вот код программы:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> myLangs;
    private final String NAMEKEY = "langname";
    private final String YEARKEY = "langyear";
    private final String SCOREKEY = "langscore";
    private final String AUTHORKEY = "langauthor";

    ArrayList<String> langNames;
    ArrayList<String> langYears;
    ArrayList<String> langScore;
    ArrayList<Object> langAuthors;

    EditText edit1;
    EditText edit2;
    EditText edit3;
    ListView langList;
    SimpleAdapter listAdapter2;
    HashMap<String, Object> hm;

    DBHelper dbHelper; // объект класса DBHelper
    SQLiteDatabase db; // объект для работы с БД

    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        Toast.makeText(langList.getContext(), "saved", 1000).show(); // сообщение
                                                                        // для
                                                                        // отслеживания
        outState.putSerializable("HashMap", myLangs); // помещаем наш основной
                                                        // массив в хранилище
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState); // вызываем метод родительского
                                                // класса
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override // данный метод вызывается при нажатии на любой пункт меню
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.about: // для пункта меню «О программе»
            onAboutClick(item);
            break;
        case R.id.addNew: // для пункта меню «Добавить язык»
            onAddNewClick(item); // этот метод нужно создать
            break;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    private void onAddNewClick(MenuItem item) {
        Intent newAct = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), InputActivity.class);
        startActivityForResult(newAct, INPUT_ACTIVITY); // вызываем активити и
                                                        // ждем от него
                                                        // результат
        // второй параметр нужен для отличия результатов при нескольких
        // дополнительных активити
    }

    private final int INPUT_ACTIVITY = 1;
    private AdapterContextMenuInfo info;
    private final int CHANGE_PICTURE = 2;

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        switch (requestCode) { // оператор выбора для определения, от какого
                                // активити пришел результат
        case INPUT_ACTIVITY: // идентификатор нашего активити ввода нового языка
            // создаем массив строк, в который записываем результаты из второго
            // окна
            String[] newItem = data.getStringArrayExtra("newItem");
            // далее из полученого массива переносим данные в список элементов
            langNames.add(0, newItem[0]); // добавляем текст из edit1 в
                                            // langNames
            langYears.add(0, newItem[1]); // добавляем текст из edit2 в
                                            // langYears
            langScore.add(0, newItem[2]);
            langAuthors.add(0, R.drawable.no_picture);
            hm = new HashMap<String, Object>(); // создаем хэш-мап
            hm.put(NAMEKEY, langNames.get(0)); // записываем в него название
                                                // языка
            hm.put(YEARKEY, langYears.get(0)); // записываем в него год создания
                                                // языка
            hm.put(SCOREKEY, langScore.get(0));
            hm.put(AUTHORKEY, R.drawable.no_picture);
            myLangs.add(0, hm); // заносим хэш-мап в начало главного массива
            listAdapter2.notifyDataSetChanged();
            putDataToDB();
            break;

        case CHANGE_PICTURE:
            if (resultCode == -1) { // если файл был выбран
                // создаем объект класса Uri (URI – Uniform Resource Identifier
                // – унифицированный идентификатор ресурсов)
                Uri uri = data.getData(); // берем URI из данных, полученных из
                                            // активити
                String path = null; // создаем переменную для хранения пути к
                                    // выбранному файлу
                // следующий код нужен для правильного отображения пути к
                // графическому файлу
                if ("content".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {// если открыт
                                                                    // был файл
                                                                    // с
                    // предопределенным системой содержимым (графический файл)
                    String[] projection = { "_data" }; // то создаем проекцию
                    Cursor cursor = null; // создаем курсор (для обращения к
                                            // системной БД)
                    // связываем курсор с запросом к системной БД с указанием
                    // URI и проекции
                    cursor = this.getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, null, null, null);
                    // получаем индекс колонки, в котором хранится нужная нам
                    // информация
                    int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("_data");
                    // переходим к первой записи и одновременно проверяем на
                    // null
                    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                        path = cursor.getString(column_index);// получаем путь к
                                                                // графическому
                                                                // файлу
                    }
                } // если файл обычный (например, текстовый),
                else
                    path = uri.getPath(); // то просто получаем путь
                // выводим сообщение с путем к файлу
                Toast.makeText(langList.getContext(), "File Uri: " + path, 1000).show();
                // в массиве langAuthors меняем элемент с номером info.position
                // (из onCreateContextMenu, это номер
                // элемента в списке, у которого было вызвано контекстное меню)
                // на путь к выбранному файлу
                langAuthors.set(info.position, path);
                // создаём хэш-мап и приравниваем его к хэш-мапу из myLangs с
                // номером info.position
                HashMap<String, Object> tempHash = myLangs.get(info.position);
                // удаляем из него данные о картинке с автором
                tempHash.remove(AUTHORKEY);
                // и вставляем новые данные с путем к выбранному графическому
                // файлу из langAuthors
                tempHash.put(AUTHORKEY, langAuthors.get(info.position));
                // заменяем в myLangs элемент с нужным номером на новый, только
                // что созданный
                myLangs.set(info.position, tempHash);
                // сигнализируем адаптеру, что данные изменились
                listAdapter2.notifyDataSetChanged();
                putDataToDB();
            }
            break;

        }
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data); // метод
                                                                // родительского
                                                                // класса
    }

    // в строковых ресурсах нужна строка с именем about_content
    public void onAboutClick(MenuItem item) { // наш метод для показа
                                                // диалогового окна с
                                                // информацией
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle(item.getTitle());
        // ищем строковый ресурс с именем about_content – в нем текст для
        // диалогового окна
        int strId = getResources().getIdentifier("about_content", "string", getPackageName());
        String strValue = getString(strId);
        if (strId != 0)
            strValue = getString(strId);
        builder.setMessage(strValue);
        builder.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
        builder.show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
        super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.context_menu, menu);
        info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) menuInfo; // сохраняем
                                                                // информацию об
                                                                // элементе,
        // у которого выбрано контекстное меню (объект info должен быть объявлен
        // как поле класса)
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.change_picture:
            onChangePictureClick();
            break;
        }
        return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
    }

    private void onChangePictureClick() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT); // создаем
                                                                // намерение для
                                                                // выбора файла
        intent.setType("file/*"); // указываем тип открываемых ресурсов
        startActivityForResult(intent, CHANGE_PICTURE); // стартуем активити и
                                                        // ждем от него
    } // результата с кодом CHANGE_PICTURE

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        langList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.langList);
        registerForContextMenu(langList);
        dbHelper = new DBHelper(this); // создаем объект для БД
        db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase(); // получаем ссылку для работы с БД

        if (savedInstanceState != null && savedInstanceState.containsKey("HashMap")) {
            myLangs = (ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>) savedInstanceState.getSerializable("HashMap");
            Toast.makeText(langList.getContext(), "From saved", 1000).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(langList.getContext(), "From create", 1000).show();
            // создаем курсор – объект для выполнения запросов к БД и получения
            // результатов из БД
            // связываем его с таблицей mytable
            Cursor c = db.query("mytable", null, null, null, null, null, null, null);
            // функция moveToFirst() курсора переходит на первую запись таблицы
            // и возвращает true,
            // или возвращает false, если записей нет
            if (!c.moveToFirst()) { // если нет записей в таблице mytable
                fillMyLangs(); // выносим заполнение массива myLangs в отдельную
                                // функцию (см. ниже)
                Toast.makeText(langList.getContext(), "DB is empty ", 1000).show(); // для
                                                                                    // отладки
                putDataToDB(); // метод для заполнения БД текущими данными из
                                // массивов (см. ниже)
            } else { // иначе, если в БД есть записи, заполняем ими наши массивы
                Toast.makeText(langList.getContext(), "From DB", 1000).show();
                langNames = new ArrayList<String>(); // создаем заново массивы
                langYears = new ArrayList<String>();
                langScore = new ArrayList<String>();
                langAuthors = new ArrayList<Object>();
                int nameColIndex = c.getColumnIndex("name"); // находим индексы
                                                                // нужных
                                                                // столбцов
                int yearColIndex = c.getColumnIndex("year");
                int scoreColIndex = c.getColumnIndex("score");
                int authorColIndex = c.getColumnIndex("author");
                do { // цикл по всем записям
                        // из текущей записи из столбца c индексом nameColIndex
                        // берем значение поля и добавляем его
                    langNames.add(c.getString(nameColIndex)); // в массив
                                                                // langNames
                    langYears.add(c.getString(yearColIndex)); // то же самое для
                                                                // langYears
                    langScore.add(c.getString(scoreColIndex));
                    // получаем значение из колонки с описанием графического
                    // ресурса картинки автора языка
                    String authorInDB = c.getString(authorColIndex);
                    // пробуем преобразовать его в число, если получается,
                    // значит взято из внутренних ресурсов
                    // т.к. все ресурсы хранятся в виде числовых констант, и
                    // добавляем в langAuthors
                    try {
                        langAuthors.add(Integer.parseInt(authorInDB));
                        // если срабатывает исключение NumberFormatException
                        // (т.е. это не число),
                        // значит там путь к внешнему файлу
                    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                        langAuthors.add(authorInDB); // записываем этот путь
                    }
                } while (c.moveToNext()); // пока есть записи в таблице, с
                                            // которой связан курсор
                fillMyLangs(); // вызываем функцию заполнения массива myLangs
            }
            Log.d("myLogs", "--- records've been put---"); // вывод в LogCat для
                                                            // отладки
            c.close(); // закрываем курсор
            c = db.query("mytable", null, null, null, null, null, null, null);// снова
            // соединяем
            // его с
            // mytable
            c.moveToFirst(); // переходим на первую запись
            // и выводим сообщение о текущем кол-ве записей в таблице mytable
            Toast.makeText(langList.getContext(), " " + c.getCount(), 1000).show();
            c.close(); // закрываем курсор
        }

        final ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> myLangs = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>(); // создаем
        // массив
        final ArrayList<String> langNames = new ArrayList<String>(
                Arrays.asList("Prospect_pobedy", "Mira", "Severnaya"));

        final ArrayList<String> langYears = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("4", "22", "60А"));

        final ArrayList<String> langScore = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("64", "32", "128"));

        ArrayList<Object> langAuthors = new ArrayList<Object>(
                Arrays.asList(R.drawable.basic, R.drawable.pascal, R.drawable.c, R.drawable.cpp, R.drawable.c_sharp,
                        R.drawable.java, R.drawable.php, R.drawable.python, R.drawable.no_picture));

        for (String s : langNames)

        {
            hm = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            hm.put(NAMEKEY, s);
            String year = langYears.get(langNames.indexOf(s));
            hm.put(YEARKEY, year);
            String score = langScore.get(langNames.indexOf(s));
            hm.put(SCOREKEY, score);
            Object author = langAuthors.get(langNames.indexOf(s));
            hm.put(AUTHORKEY, author);
            myLangs.add(hm);
        }
        edit1 = (EditText)

        findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        edit2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        edit3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);
        langList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.langList);

        langList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view1, int pos, long id) {
                // преобразуем View к типу LinearLayout, т.к. наш элемент списка
                // – это LinearLayout
                // с помещенными в него компонентами
                LinearLayout myLay = (LinearLayout) view1;
                // берем нулевой элемент в компоновке (это еще одна компоновка –
                // см. рис. 21)
                LinearLayout myLay2 = (LinearLayout) myLay.getChildAt(0);
                // во вложенной компоновке берем нулевой элемент (это TextView)
                TextView text = (TextView) myLay2.getChildAt(0);
                // и показываем текст из полученного TextView во всплывающем
                // сообщении
                // Toast.makeText(langList.getContext(), "Selected: "+pos+"
                // "+text.getText(), 1000).show();
                String sometext = text.getText().toString(); // 2
                showMessage(sometext);
            }
        });

        listAdapter2 = new SimpleAdapter(this, myLangs, R.layout.my_list3,
                new String[] { NAMEKEY, YEARKEY, SCOREKEY, AUTHORKEY },
                new int[] { R.id.text1, R.id.text2, R.id.text3, R.id.imageView1 });
        langList.setAdapter(listAdapter2);
        Button okButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        okButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                langNames.add(0, edit1.getText().toString());
                langYears.add(0, edit2.getText().toString());
                langScore.add(0, edit3.getText().toString());

                hm = new HashMap<String, Object>();
                hm.put(NAMEKEY, langNames.get(0));
                hm.put(YEARKEY, langYears.get(0));
                hm.put(SCOREKEY, langScore.get(0));
                hm.put(AUTHORKEY, R.drawable.no_picture);
                myLangs.add(0, hm);
                listAdapter2.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
    }

    private void fillMyLangs() { // метод для заполнения массива myLangs
        for (String s : langNames) {
            hm = new HashMap<String, Object>(); // создаем хэш-мап
            hm.put(NAMEKEY, s); // записываем в него название языка
            String year = langYears.get(langNames.indexOf(s)); // находим
                                                                // соответствующий
                                                                // языку год
            hm.put(YEARKEY, year); // записываем в хэш-мап год создания языка
            String score = langScore.get(langScore.indexOf(s));
            hm.put(SCOREKEY, score);
            Object author = langAuthors.get(langNames.indexOf(s));
            hm.put(AUTHORKEY, author); // записываем в хэш-мап автора языка
            myLangs.add(hm); // заносим хэш-мап в главный массив
        }
    }

    private void putDataToDB() { // метод для заполнения БД текущими данными из
                                    // массивов
        db.delete("mytable", null, null); // очищаем таблицу mytable
        for (String s : langNames) { // цикл по всем элементам массива langNames
            int i = langNames.indexOf(s); // получаем номер текущего элемента
            // создаем объект, аналог хэш-мапа, но для полей таблиц (задаем пары
            // «имя столбца» – значение)
            ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
            cv.put("number", i); // для поля number задаем значение i
            cv.put("name", s); // для поля name задаем значение s
            cv.put("year", langYears.get(i)); // для поля year задаем значение
                                                // langYears.get(i)
            cv.put("score", langScore.get(i));
            cv.put("author", langAuthors.get(i).toString()); // то же самое для
                                                                // author
            db.insert("mytable", null, cv); // вставляем все данные из cv в
                                            // mytable
        }

    }

    protected void showMessage(String str) {
        // создаем диалоговое окно, параметр – контекст, который берем у списка
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(langList.getContext());
        builder.setTitle(str); // заголовок диалогового окна
        // создаем переменную для нахождения строкового ресурса (см. текст после
        // примера)
        // ищем в строковых ресурсах строку с именем, которое совпадает с
        // значением str
        // и берем её идентификатор
        int strId = getResources().getIdentifier(str, "string", getPackageName());
        String strValue = "";
        // если ресурс был найден, т.е. strId!=0, то по найденному
        // идентификатору получаем значение строки
        if (strId != 0)
            strValue = getString(strId);
        builder.setMessage(strValue); // задаем содержимое окна
        // создаем в окне кнопку ОК и задаем ее функционал
        builder.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.dismiss(); // Закрывает диалоговое окно
            }
        });
        AlertDialog dialog = builder.create(); // создаем диалоговое окно через
                                                // построитель
        dialog.show(); // показываем диалоговое окно
    }
}
```

Если закомментировать строки от 275 до 344, программа запускается и работает, только без сохранения данных. 
Вот лог LogCat:

```
05-15 21:46:12.186: E/AndroidRuntime(2801): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-15 21:46:12.186: E/AndroidRuntime(2801): Process: com.example.lab3, PID: 2801
05-15 21:46:12.186: E/AndroidRuntime(2801): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.lab3/com.example.lab3.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-15 21:46:12.186: E/AndroidRuntime(2801):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
05-15 21:46:12.186: E/AndroidRuntime(2801):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
05-15 21:46:12.186: E/AndroidRuntime(2801):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
05-15 21:46:12.186: E/AndroidRuntime(2801):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
05-15 21:46:12.186: E/AndroidRuntime(2801):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
05-15 21:46:12.186: E/AndroidRuntime(2801):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
05-15 21:46:12.186: E/AndroidRuntime(2801):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
05-15 21:46:12.186: E/AndroidRuntime(2801):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-15 21:46:12.186: E/AndroidRuntime(2801):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
05-15 21:46:12.186: E/AndroidRuntime(2801):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
05-15 21:46:12.186: E/AndroidRuntime(2801):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
05-15 21:46:12.186: E/AndroidRuntime(2801):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-15 21:46:12.186: E/AndroidRuntime(2801): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-15 21:46:12.186: E/AndroidRuntime(2801):     at com.example.lab3.MainActivity.fillMyLangs(MainActivity.java:424)
05-15 21:46:12.186: E/AndroidRuntime(2801):     at com.example.lab3.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:288)
05-15 21:46:12.186: E/AndroidRuntime(2801):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
05-15 21:46:12.186: E/AndroidRuntime(2801):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
05-15 21:46:12.186: E/AndroidRuntime(2801):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
05-15 21:46:12.186: E/AndroidRuntime(2801):     ... 11 more
05-15 21:46:12.206: W/ActivityManager(418):   Force finishing activity com.example.lab3/.MainActivity
05-15 21:46:12.546: I/WindowManager(418): Screenshot max retries 4 of Token{ae0ec618 ActivityRecord{ae0ec4b8 u0 com.example.lab3/.MainActivity t37 f}} appWin=Window{ae08f378 u0 Starting com.example.lab3} drawState=4
05-15 21:46:12.546: W/WindowManager(418): Screenshot failure taking screenshot for (480x800) to layer 21010
05-15 21:46:13.056: W/ActivityManager(418): Activity pause timeout for ActivityRecord{ae0ec4b8 u0 com.example.lab3/.MainActivity t37 f}
05-15 21:46:13.456: W/EGL_emulation(581): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
05-15 21:46:14.156: I/ActivityManager(418): Killing 2559:com.android.documentsui/u0a23 (adj 15): empty for 2579s
05-15 21:46:14.456: E/SoundPool(418): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
05-15 21:46:14.456: W/AudioService(418): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
05-15 21:46:14.526: E/SoundPool(418): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
05-15 21:46:14.526: W/AudioService(418): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
05-15 21:46:14.576: E/SoundPool(418): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
05-15 21:46:14.576: W/AudioService(418): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
05-15 21:46:14.626: E/SoundPool(418): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
05-15 21:46:14.626: W/AudioService(418): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
05-15 21:46:14.716: E/SoundPool(418): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
05-15 21:46:14.716: W/AudioService(418): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
05-15 21:46:14.776: E/SoundPool(418): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressStandard.ogg
05-15 21:46:14.776: W/AudioService(418): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressStandard.ogg
05-15 21:46:14.786: E/SoundPool(418): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressSpacebar.ogg
05-15 21:46:14.786: W/AudioService(418): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressSpacebar.ogg
05-15 21:46:14.786: E/SoundPool(418): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressDelete.ogg
05-15 21:46:14.786: W/AudioService(418): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressDelete.ogg
05-15 21:46:14.796: E/SoundPool(418): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressReturn.ogg
05-15 21:46:14.796: W/AudioService(418): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressReturn.ogg
05-15 21:46:14.806: E/SoundPool(418): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressInvalid.ogg
05-15 21:46:14.806: W/AudioService(418): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressInvalid.ogg
05-15 21:46:14.816: W/AudioService(418): onLoadSoundEffects(), Error -1 while loading samples
05-15 21:46:14.906: W/InputMethodManagerService(418): Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@ae266820 attribute=null, token = android.os.BinderProxy@ae03e450
05-15 21:46:14.926: I/Process(2801): Sending signal. PID: 2801 SIG: 9
05-15 21:46:15.036: I/ActivityManager(418): Process com.example.lab3 (pid 2801) has died.
```

Comment: а зачем вы перегоняете данные из курсора в Map - операция абсолютно бессмысленная и приводящая только к перерасходу памяти устройства, потерям времени и ресурсов, это вас так в вашем универе научили? Гораздо [более правильным](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/545773/177345) будет использовать адаптер, который работает непосредственно с курсором (`SimpleCursorAdapter`), а данные для отображения формируются через запросы в БД.

Comment: Так же получать при клике контент из виджета - плохая практика, правильно получать эти данные из модели (в случае CursorAdapter метод getItem() вернет их) Пример [в этом ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/612783/177345). Вообще для лабы очень слабо, очень много проблемных мест, надеюсь вы не на android-разработчика учитесь, иначе вам нужно гораздо больше времени уделять всему этому.

Answer (score 1):

Обычно это связано с временем жизни активити. Но в вашем случае `stacktrace` указывает, что у вас ошибка в методе `fillMyLangs`, потому что все списки инициализируются только в том случае, если у вас нет данных в базе, а сейчас если в базе есть данные они `null`.