# Android Studio: не грузит БД SQLite

Tags: java, android, sqlite

Должные грузиться данные из подключенной БД. Вместо этого приложение при нажатии на нужный фрагмент вылетает с ошибкой. Не могу понять, в чем может быть причина?

**Код лога:**

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: com.example.gukov.guap, PID: 3109
>   android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID
>   0x19   at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:274)   at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:4122)   at
>   com.example.gukov.guap.DirectionAdapter.onBindViewHolder(DirectionAdapter.java:45)
>   at
>   com.example.gukov.guap.DirectionAdapter.onBindViewHolder(DirectionAdapter.java:17)
>   at
>   android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6482)   at
>   android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.bindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6515)
>   at
>   android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryBindViewHolderByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5458)
>   at
>   android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5724)
>   at
>   android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5563)
>   at
>   android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5559)
>   at
>   android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2229)
>   at
>   android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1556)
>   at
>   android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1516)
>   at
>   android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:608)
>   at
>   android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:3693)
>   at
>   android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onMeasure(RecyclerView.java:3109)
>   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)   at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5463)
>   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)   at
>   android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)   at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5463)
>   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)   at
>   android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)   at
>   android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout.internalMeasureChildren(ConstraintLayout.java:934)
>   at
>   android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout.onMeasure(ConstraintLayout.java:973)
>   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)   at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5463)
>   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)   at
>   android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:139)
>   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)   at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5463)
>   at
>   android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1436)
>   at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:722) 
>   at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:613)   at
>   android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)   at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5463)
>   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)   at
>   android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)   at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5463)
>   at
>   android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1436)
>   at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:722) 
>   at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:613)   at
>   android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)   at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5463)
>   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)   at
>   com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2560)
>   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)   at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2001)   at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1166)
>   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1372)
>   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1054)   at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5779)
>   at
>   android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:767)
>   at android.view.Choreographer.d

**Код DatabaseHelper.java**

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static String DB_NAME = "meetpeople.db";
    private static String DB_PATH = "";

    private SQLiteDatabase myDatabase;
    private final Context myContext;
    private static final int DB_VERSION = 1;

    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DB_NAME, null, 1);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=15) {
            DB_PATH = context.getApplicationInfo().dataDir + "/databases/";
        }
        else {
            DB_PATH = Environment.getDataDirectory() + context.getPackageName() + "/databases/";
        }
        this.myContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int i, int i1) {

    }

    public void checkAndCopyDatabase() {
        boolean dbExist = checkDatebase();
        if (dbExist) {
            Log.d("TAG", "database already exist");
        } else {
            this.getReadableDatabase();
        }
        try {
            copyDatabase();;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.d("TAG", "Error copy database");
        }
    }

    public boolean checkDatebase() {
        SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;
        try {
            String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
            checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
        } catch (SQLException e) {

        }
        if (checkDB != null) {
            checkDB.close();
        }
        return checkDB != null ? true : false;
    }

    public void copyDatabase() throws IOException {
        InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);
        String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int lenght;
        while ((lenght = myInput.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            myOutput.write(buffer, 0, lenght);
        }
        myOutput.flush();
        myOutput.close();
        myInput.close();

    }

    public void openDatabase() {
        String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        myDatabase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
    }

    public synchronized void close() {
        if (myDatabase != null) {
            myDatabase.close();
        }
        super.close();
    }

    public Cursor QueryData(String query) {
        return myDatabase.rawQuery(query, null);
    }
}
```

**Код фрагмента SearchFragment**

```
public class SearchFragment extends Fragment {

    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    DirectionAdapter adapter;

    DatabaseHelper databaseHelper;
    Cursor cursor;

    List<Direction> directionList;

    public SearchFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_search, container, false);

        FloatingActionButton buttonAdd = (FloatingActionButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.floatingActionButton);

        buttonAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity().getApplication().getApplicationContext(), AddMeetActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }

        });


        directionList = new ArrayList<>();

        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity().getApplication().getApplicationContext()));




        databaseHelper= new DatabaseHelper(getActivity().getApplication().getApplicationContext());
        try {
            databaseHelper.checkAndCopyDatabase();
            databaseHelper.openDatabase();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            cursor = databaseHelper.QueryData("select * from directions");
            if (cursor != null) {
                if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                    do {

                        directionList.add(
                                new Direction(
                                        cursor.getInt(0),
                                        cursor.getInt(2),
                                        cursor.getString(1),
                                        cursor.getInt(3)));

                    } while (cursor.moveToNext());
                }
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }



        DirectionAdapter adapter = new DirectionAdapter(getActivity().getApplication().getApplicationContext(), directionList);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

        return rootView;
    }}`
```

**Код адаптера DirectionAdapter**

```
`public class DirectionAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<DirectionAdapter.DirectionViewHolder> {

    private Context mCtx;
    private List<Direction> directionList;

    public DirectionAdapter(Context mCtx, List<Direction> directionList) {
        this.mCtx = mCtx;
        this.directionList = directionList;
    }

    @Override
    public DirectionViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mCtx);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.direction, null);

        return new DirectionViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(DirectionViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Direction direction = directionList.get(position);

        String colorName = "colorDirection_" + direction.getDirectionColor();
        int colorId = mCtx.getResources().getIdentifier(colorName, "color", mCtx.getPackageName());

        holder.relativeLayoutDirection.setBackgroundResource(colorId);
        holder.textViewDirectionTitle.setText(direction.getDirectionTitle());
        holder.textViewDirectionCount.setText(direction.getDirectionCount());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return directionList.size();
    }

    class DirectionViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView textViewDirectionTitle, textViewDirectionCount;
        RelativeLayout relativeLayoutDirection;

        public DirectionViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);


            textViewDirectionTitle = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewDirectionTitle);
            textViewDirectionCount = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewDirectionCount);
            relativeLayoutDirection = itemView.findViewById(R.id.relativeLayoutDirection);
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Ошибка в том, что вы помещаете в свой список значения типа `int`. Метод `setText()` при выводе на экран воспринимает это, как идинтификатор ресурса (а не число, которое надо отобразить на экране, такая перегрузка у метода при единственном аргументе типа `int`). Соответственно строкового ресурса с таким ID в вашем проекте не нашлось, о чем вам и сообщается в стектрейсе.

Приведите значения типа `int` к типу `String` (`Integer.toString(int value)`), чтобы они отображались как текст.

PS: хотелось бы, чтобы вы очень внимательно прочитали первые абзацы из [этого ответа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/545773/177345) и поняли, что работать в адаптере надо непосредственно с курсором, полученным от БД, а не перегонять данные в динамические списки во избежании боли - ничего, кроме дополнительного расхода ресурсов устройства и потерь времени вы с такой реализацией не "выгадаете".

У контекста есть специальный метод для получения пути к БД, включая ее имя (не надо добавлять отдельно), который работает корректно на всех версиях API:

`DB_PATH = context.getDatabasePath(DATABASE_NAME).toString();`

подробнее смотрите реализацию класса `SQLiteOpenHelper` с копированием готовой БД в [этом ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/612783/177345)