# Как в андроид пополнять таблицу через БД?

Tags: java, android

У меня есть таблица в БД со значениями `name` , `surname`, `email` и т.д.

Мне в Андроид приложении нужно взять из этой таблицы Имя `name` и Фамилию `surname` и запихать в таблицу активити...

Метод взятия данных из БД в `DatabaseHelper` я написал и выглядит он так:

```
public Cursor getAllRegisteredPersons() {
    database = this.getReadableDatabase();
    return database.rawQuery(
    "SELECT " + COLUMN_NAME + 
    " , " + COLUMN_SURNAME + 
    " , " + 
    "FROM " + TABLE_NAME, null);
}
```

В `ListOfRegisteredActivity.java` я написал такую конструкцию как:

```
dbHelper = new DBHelper(this);
Cursor regPersons = dbHelper.getAllRegisteredPersons();
if (regPersons.getCount() == 0) {
   //TODO Написать на экране что пользователей нету
} else {
    ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> surnames = new ArrayList<String>();
    while (regPersons.moveToNext()) {
        names.add(regPersons.getString(0));
        surnames.add(regPersons.getString(1));
    }
    Collections.sort(names);
    Collections.sort(surnames);
}
```

Вот тут дальше я уже не знаю что и как вывести в виде простой таблицы как на данном скриншоте

[image: Пример таблицы]

А вот и сам `.xml` для 1 пользователя

```
<TableRow
    android:background="#cccccc"
    android:padding="5dp">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="@string/person_count"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="@string/person_name"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="@string/person_surname"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
</TableRow>

<TableRow android:padding="5dp">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="1"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="Эльмир"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="Исмаилзаде"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
</TableRow>
```

Как сделать так, чтобы данная таблица генерировалась автоматически через базу данных?

Comment: мб, использовать ListView с кастомным адаптером!

Comment: @Виктор Как это сделать?  Я просто новичок в сфере андроид, напишите в ответе пожалуйста :)

Comment: http://devcolibri.com/1587 я думаю тут достаточно хорошо описана логика, а там уже под себя пример делаете.

Comment: @Виктор Я посмотрел, но ничего так и не понял что там... И вообще причем там иконки? Я же не иконку беру... А значения с базы данных...

Comment: а Вы и не привязывайтесь к иконкам а привязывайтесь к идее, что Вам мешает взять вместо иконок texview и выгрузить в него то что нужно?

Comment: @Виктор Аааааа,все все я понял)) Понял логику) Нужно создать `Database adapter` который автоматически берет данный с бд генерирует лист и вставляет в активити)

Comment: Если вы работаете с БД то используйте SimpleCursorAdapter, зачем тратить ресурсы на бессмысленную перегонку данных в ArrayList. Сами данные в адаптер должны поставляться одним объектом, а не отдельно имена и отдельно фамилии (не говоря о том, что отсортированные отдельно имена и фамилии не будут соответствовать друг другу). Сортировку так же следует выполнять средствами БД. Смотрите [этот ответ](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/523763/177345)

Comment: @pavlofff Да, я понял.. Ну я просто новичок и мало что знаю... про `SimpleCurosrAdapter` только что узнал... Ща пытаюсь смотрю что и как надо делать) Спасибо за ссылку, думаю пригодиться)